# Raster to Polygon Conversion with shift

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vectorization

The Raster to Polygon Conversion results in strange polygons. I must have changed something in the settings, but have no idea what it could be.

Does anyone can help?

[image]

The red line is the polygone outline

Comment: What coordinate system is defined on each of your raster, polygon features and map's dataframe?  I suspect that your raster and polygon features do not have the same.

Comment: It's the same on each

Comment: But I noticed that when the output is a shapefile, the conversion works perfectly. The problem appears only when I save the output into a file geodatabase.

Comment: What are the precise tool parameter values that you used when working vs not working?

Comment: Thank you for the support. I found the error. The X Y resolution and tolerance values were to high in comparison to the raster resolution.

Comment: That may be useful to post as an answer if you flesh it out to a paragraph or two.